# sub batch file exit code in Java

Tags: java, batch-file

I have a batch file A which is called in a java program with `Process process = new ProcessBuilder("...").start()`.

And the batch file A calls another batch file B. In my case, B's exit code is different from A's exit code since B could fail from time to time. My problem here is that in the java program, I cannot seem to possibly get the exit code of B by any means. I wonder if there's a way to achieve what I want.

Comment: Assuming A can look at the exit code of B, it could pass it along.

Comment: just think this way: in Java, you have a `methodA` which call `methodB`.  How can the caller of `methodA` know the return value of `methodB`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Batch A.bat calls B.bat
Batch B.bat will return a random errorlevel 0/1
Batch A will handover the same erorlevel to the caller/console

```
:: A.bat
@Echo off
Echo about to call B.bat
Call B.bat
Echo Back in A.bat Errorlevel=%Errorlevel%=
Exit /B %Errorlevel%
```

---

```
:: B.bat
@Echo off
Echo this is B.bat
Set /A "RandErr=%Random% %% 2"
Echo Exit /B %RandErr%
     Exit /B %RandErr%
```

Sample run:

```
> a
about to call B.bat
this is B.bat
Exit /B 0
Back in A.bat Errorlevel=0=

> a
about to call B.bat
this is B.bat
Exit /B 1
Back in A.bat Errorlevel=1=
```